# Is it possible for 32 bit NSIS to launch a 64 bit program?

Tags: windows, installation, nsis

I'm porting a windows program from 32 -> 64 bit.  It has a 32 bit installer which is written using NSIS.  Can I launch one of my new 64 bit exes using the 32 bit NSIS installer?  I don't think there is a 64 bit version of NSIS...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NSIS uses two Win32 APIs to execute processes [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) (thru [`ExecShell`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.1.3)) and [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx) (thru [`Exec`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.1.2) and [`ExecWait`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.1.4)), both of them can run 64 bit process (x64) from NSIS 32 bit process (as long as you're running on 64 bit OS).

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't think it was possible to create a 64 bit process from a 32 bit one.  Is there anything special I have to do?

Comment: I consistently find that when I launch things like cmd they are stuck in 32-bit mode and cannot run any 64-bit utilities (windows 10 64-bit). @sonyisda1's answer is better

Comment: @Shorin I know how to solve this problem, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72050108/3937190).

Answer (score 15):

Sure you can, NSIS doesn't impose any restrictions and what's really nifty about NSIS is if you have both 32 and 64 bit versions of your app, you can do a combined installer, and install the required files on a per-architecture basis. e.g.

```
!include "x64.nsh"

${If} ${RunningX64}
    File ..\x64\blah.exe
${Else}
    File ..\x86\blah.exe
${EndIf}
```

Comment: Hi i know this is old but i have tried this and it still seems to install the 32bit.exe if i try this method. Why oh why?

Comment: @DanielCasserly there shouldn't be anything magical - that's the code I'm still using. It was grabbed from an example on the NSIS site when I was first building my installer

Answer (score 5):

For executing processes needing 64-bit operation I found the default NSIS execution would not automatically run in 64-bit mode.  I encountered this when trying to run DISM to install .NET Framework 3.5.  DISM would error out stating:

> "You cannot service a running 64-bit operating system with a 32-bit
>   version of DISM."

To resolve I added needed to add `DisableX64FSRedirection` before the call that needs 64-bit operation.  See below for example:

```
${If} ${RunningX64}
   ${DisableX64FSRedirection}
   DetailPrint "Disabling Windows 64-bit file system redirection"
${EndIf}

nsExec::ExecToStack 'Dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3'

${If} ${RunningX64}
   ${EnableX64FSRedirection}
   DetailPrint "Re-enabling Windows 64-bit file system redirection"
${EndIf}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for `powershell.exe` launches a 32-bit PowerShell window

Comment: @AndreiKrasutski this is a known issue as noted in the pitfall section [here](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/PowerShell_support)

Answer (score 1):

just to add more descriptive

have a look,
         http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=44048

Answer (score 0):

Well.. there are some restrictions here.. for instance, try run 
odbcconf.exe to install a driver. I have not been able to figure out a way to make that come in as a 64bit entry.
Same way I think as if you (in a 64bit system) start "powershell x86" as admin, then run cmd and odbcconf from there - no easy way to get around it that I can find, making odbcconf do x64

Answer (score 0):

To launch a 64-bit PowerShell window and run a script from 32-bit setup

```
!include "x64.nsh"

SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
${If} ${RunningX64}
    NsExec::ExecToStack "$WINDIR\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NonInteractive -File .\example.ps1"
${Else}
    NsExec::ExecToStack "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NonInteractive -File .\example.ps1"
${EndIf}
Pop $0
DetailPrint "Program returned $0"
```